# Coldfusion mail() object set authentication

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfmail

I'm receiving a DMARC policy error when I try to send an email using ColdFusion. I believe the issue is because I'm not fully authenticating the email. How can I authenticate passing server, username, and password using cfscript mail().

```
mailerService = new mail();
mailerService.setTo("test@yahoo.com");
mailerService.setFrom("test@gmail.com");
mailerService.setSubject("TEST");
mailerService.setType("html");
var mailBody = "This is a Test";
mailerService.send(body=mailBody);
```

Is there a mailService.server, .password, and .user?

Thanks

Comment: If they aren't configured globally in the CF Admin, then you have to specify then with each request to the mail function. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/script-functions-implemented-as-cfcs/mail.html "All attributes supported by the tag cfmail can be used as attribute-value pairs." https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmail.html

Comment: If I try to set mailService.server it returns: The method server was not found in component mail.cfc

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 You need to use `setServer()`

Comment: You can set attributes by `mailService.set_AttributeName_(attribute_value)` or `mailService.setAttributes(_attribute-value_pair_)` formats.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.